# Sprite kit double tap detection

Tags: ios, iphone, touch, sprite-kit

I'm using spriteKit for my game, I detect single tap and double tap by using the following code:

```
    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.tapCount == 1){

        [self.tapQueue addObject:@1];

        NSLog(@"touch.tapCount == 1 :)");

    }

    if (touch.tapCount == 2) {

       [self.tapQueue addObject:@2];

       NSLog(@"touch.tapCount == 2 :)");
    }
}

-(void)processUserTapsForUpdate:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    for (NSNumber* tapCount in [self.tapQueue copy]) {

        if ([tapCount unsignedIntegerValue] == 1)
            [self singleTap];

        if ([tapCount unsignedIntegerValue] == 2)
            [self doubleTap];

        [self.tapQueue removeObject:tapCount];
    }
}
```

This code detect single tap but when it detect double tap it detect single tap with it. How can I difference between single tap and double tap?

Thanks

Comment: either use a double-tap gesture recognizer, or have the touch began start waiting for another touch before running the single-tap code once enough time has elapsed (ie 0.3 seconds) without any consecutive tap

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying that a single tap is reported twice during a double tap, once for the single tap and once for the double tap, before the double tap is reported?

Also to try answering your question, create a global tapCount instead of relying on the tapCount from the touch events.  Or a boolean var tappedOnce where you check to make sure its double tapped.

Comment: once for the single tap and once for the double tap, before the double tap is reported? YES